# this params in cakephp 2.3 returns null

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

how to get the information in cakephp 2.3 which was in `$this->params` in cakephp 1.3 ?

So, the following array with the information of, say, controller, action, arguments, url etc.

```
Array
(
    [controller] => posts
    [action] => view
    [named] => Array
        (
        )

    [pass] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

    [plugin] => 
    [form] => Array
        (
        )

    [url] => Array
        (
            [url] => posts/view/3
        )

    [isAjax] => 
)
```

debugging `$this->request` and `$this->params` inside `beforeFilter()` in my AppController it just shows `null` for both of them.

Cake version 2.3.1

**EDITED**

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

From Cake 2.x you can retrieve:

- POST data by `$this->request->data`
- GET data by `$this->params`

Also note that you can access to the data through array

```
$this->request->data['variable'];
```

and through object:

```
$this->request->data('variable');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but with non of them I could get the info I wanted. (I changed a little the question). Thanks

Comment: I just left construct part from cake 1.3, the problem was in that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just left from cakephp 1.3

```
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}
```

this part in my app controller, as soon as I removed it, `$this->params` returned the right thing.